# get datagridview cell value on first index changing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview (dgv) and set some shortcut for it. I want to get my desired cell value when dgv `selectedIndexChanged` .
this is what I've done for `selectedIndexChanged` event:

```
if (dgv.Rows.Count > 0)
{
      lblId.Text = dgv.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
      lblStaffName.Text = dgv.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
      lblStock.Text = dgv.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();  
}
```

and defined some shortcut for my dgv.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
  if (keyData == (Keys.Alt | Keys.Down))
   {
      if (dgv.Rows.Count > 0)
       {
          dgv.Focus();
          if (dgv.CurrentRow.Index < (dgv.Rows.Count - 1))
            {
                dgv.Rows[dgv.CurrentRow.Index + 1].Selected = true;
                dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgv.CurrentRow.Index + 1;
                pnl.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Lime);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

**NOTE:** as you can see, when I press `Alt+keyDown` dgv index will increase and change to one step more. 
My problem is when I pressed `Alt+keyDown` the index change and selected as well **but the value won't get new value until I press again `Alt+keyDown` twice!**
Is there any event that I must writing code in there? thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the selected index in a data-bound `DataGridView` it's better to rely on the binding context this way:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Alt | Keys.Down))
    {
        var bc = dgv.BindingContext[dgv.DataSource, dgv.DataMember];
        if (bc.Position < bc.Count - 1)
            bc.Position++;
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

But if the `DataGridView` is not data-bound or just for learning purpose you want to fix your code, you can write such code:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Alt | Keys.Down))
    {
        if (dgv.CurrentCell == null)
        {
            if (dgv.ColumnCount >= 1 && dgv.RowCount >= 1)
            {
                dgv.CurrentCell = dgv[0, 0];
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var rowIndex = dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            var columnIndex = dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            if (rowIndex < dgv.RowCount - 1)
            {
                dgv.CurrentCell = dgv[columnIndex, rowIndex + 1];
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

I also removed `dgv.Focus()` because when you use shortcuts to navigate between rows, you don't need focus, but if you need it for any reason, use it.